# How do I write a jQuery selector to match two elements whose ids start with the same string

Tags: jquery

I have 2 loader images, with element ids loader1 and loader2. I bind to the first one with:

```
$('#loader1')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

How can I bind the same code to loader2 without repeating the whole thing?

Comment: If you actually want to select a number of elements with ID's that start with the same thing you can use $('[id^="value"]'). Otherwise, Alexey's answer is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [*attribute starts with* selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`^=`):

```
$("[id^=loader]")
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

If you can also include the tag name, that will help on many browsers, as jQuery's selector engine can use the tag name to narrow down the list of candidates before looking at the `id` value. E.g., if both are `img` elements, then:

```
$("img[id^=loader]")
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
;
```

Comment: Not optimal in terms of speed. This selector cannot be queried with browser's internal functions.

Comment: @Alexey Lebedev: It can with `querySelectorAll` (if the browser supports it).

Comment: @Alexey: Amusingly, I was just going back to suggest how to improve its speed, although as @Felix points out, on some browsers it'll be fast anyway.

Comment: @AKWF: Quick eye, I saw it almost immediately and thought I'd slipped the correction in before you noticed. Drat. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#loader1, #loader2')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

See [jQuery Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) documentation.

Comment: This works for a handful of elements, but should you need to do this for many objects, it is best to use a class.

Comment: @Dutchie432: Sure, but the OP mentions `2` elements.

Comment: @Felix: Absolutely. I am not trying to take away from your answer, I was just embellishing for further clarity.

Answer (score 4):

This should help you:

```
$('div[id^=loader]')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    })
```

I used div, but you can use every html tag for this: p, span, b etc.

You have to use ^= selector, where ^= means starts with. More information can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/.
All selectors are listed here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Yeah, that's slower than listing only elements you know id's or classes, but you don't need to know every name and count of them ;)

Answer (score 4):

The **proper** way to do this, in general, would be to give both elements the same class name... This would also make it much easier if you need to handle more than 2 or 3 elements.

```
<img src="image1.png" class="loader" id="loader1" />
<img src="image2.png" class="loader" id="loader2" />
<img src="image3.png" class="loader" id="completelyDifferentId" />
```

Then you can easily access them this way

```
$('.loader').hide().ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```